# Count Value Exclude Duplicated ID

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','2','3','3','4','5'],
                    'event': ['Basket','Soccer','Soccer','Basket','Soccer','Basket','Soccer']})
```

I want to count unique values of event but exclude the repeated id. The result I expect are:

```
event   count   
Basket  3       
Soccer  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
df1.groupby('event').agg({'id':lambda x: len(pd.unique(x))})

# OR

df1.groupby(['event']).agg(['nunique'])
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How if the id is an index?

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the duplicates in your dataframe usingthe function drop_duplicates:

```
 df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
```

Then, you simply need to group by event and use the count aggregation function:

```
df1 = df1.groupby("event").agg("count")
```